# Angular 1.x: Using select & ng-options with a custom filter

Tags: angularjs, select, lodash, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

## preface

I have written a custom filter that excludes currently selected options from the list of available options for several `<select>` inputs.

codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/XdjNWa?editors=1010

**template implementation**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="vc.cols[0].attr" 
    ng-options="opt.attr as opt.name for opt in vc.opts | excludedAttrs:vc.cols">
```

**filter**

```
.filter('excludedAttrs', function () {
    return function (opts, cols) {
        return _.differenceWith(opts, cols, function (opt, col) {
            return opt.attr === col.attr;
        });
    };
})
```

## the problem

I'm not sure if it's my misunderstanding of Lodash's `differenceWith` ([API docs](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith)) or if there is some subtly in using filters with a `<select>` over other inputs.

As I understand `differenceWith`, it's meant to compare 2 arrays and utilizes a *comparator* function that returns true if they are to be excluded.  The filter actually works, but why is it not rendering the `ng-model` default value properly or the selected value?

Comment: I think the correct syntax is `filter:excludedAttrs:vc.cols`

Comment: Unfortunately that would require an `excludedAttrs` function on my viewController and it would need to change to process a single object against the current selections. I'm trying to keep the viewController light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the select not showing the currently selected `ng-model` was because the actual `<option/>` was not present in the `ng-options` due to the filter excluding it in the collection.

In order to fix this, I needed to *exclude* the currently selected value (i.e. the `ng-model` from being ... well, from being excluded.  Basically I had to add it back into the filtered `ng-options`.

codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/XdjNWa?editors=1010

**template implementation**

```
<select ng-model="vc.cols[0].attr" 
    ng-options="opt.attr as opt.name for opt in vc.opts | excludedAttrs:vc.cols:0">
```

**fixed filter**

```
.filter('excludedAttrs', function () {
    return function (opts, cols, i) {

        // fix
        cols = _.without(cols, cols[i]);
        // end fix

        return _.differenceWith(opts, cols, function (opt, col) {
            return opt.attr === col.attr;
        });
    };
})
```